# JQuery append on click of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form which does a small calculation and display data in table rows. I have also added a button to remove each row at the end. But when I do the calculation couple of times the button gets duplicated. Please refer to the image below.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dfoqe.png)

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atLab6sp/26/)

Following is how I append the button

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#calculate').click(function () {
    var removeBtn = $('<button class="removeBtn" id="removeBtn">Remove</button>');
                    $('.row-time').append(removeBtn);

        });
    });
```

I don't understand why the button gets duplicated everytime I add a new row.

Comment: You don't specify the specific row to add the button to so its adding it to **all** rows because you use a class as selector i.e. a group of rows

Comment: @ Reopen Reviewers - The duplicate target question, which is by the same author, has been deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `last` for last class.

```
$('.row-time:last').append(removeBtn);
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shree/atLab6sp/27/)